# ¿Cómo añadir widgets en función a valores contenidos en un arreglo?

Tags: python, tkinter, numpy, interfaz-gráfica

***¡Hola Comunidad!***

Dispongo que una GUI con tkinter en la que se desea mostrar un número indeterminado de etiquetas con diversos valores. La funcionalidad de la aplicación es que un usuario pueda ingresar su nombre y apellido, y, posteriormente, empezar a cargar una serie de datos, como lo son materias, notas y profesor.

Primeramente, se le pedirá al usuario que ingrese su nombre y apellido. Luego, al presionar un botón con el texto "Siguiente" se le mostrará un mensaje incrustado en un widget `tk.Text`, con la opción de poder añadir datos adicionales. Estos datos el usuario podrá ingresarlos en el orden que le plazca, en función a la selección que marque con el `tk.Radiobutton`.

Luego, podrá empezar a añadir los otros datos (Materia, Nota y Profesor). Dispondrá de dos formas de añadirlos, sea primero colocando la nota y luego el nombre del profesor o viceversa.

Si llega a concluir la operación de agregar dicha información adicional, se deberá cargar una serie de widgets que muestren todos los datos que ha ingresado. Las posiciones de estos "widgets adicionales" tendrán un patrón establecido y deberán respetar el orden en que fueron añadidos. Este patrón deberá ser:
MATERIA, NOTA, PROFESOR

El código tiene la siguiente composición:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        # Contenedor principal
        cont_fm = tk.Frame(self.root)
        cont_fm.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

        # Contenedor de los datos
        datos_fm = tk.Frame(cont_fm)
        datos_fm.grid(row=0, column=0)

        def siguiente():
            resultado_fm = tk.Frame(cont_fm)
            resultado_fm.grid(row=1, column=0)

            op = tk.IntVar()
            def opcionales():
                # El usuario ingresará ciertos datos opcionales en el orden que deseé
                # Variables involucradas
                materia = tk.StringVar()
                nota = tk.DoubleVar()
                profe = tk.StringVar()

                # Opción 1: Primero ingresa la nota y después el nombre del profesor
                if op.get() == 1:
                    ventana = tk.Toplevel()
                    ventana.resizable(0,0)

                    def anotar():
                        # Se crea un arreglo para mantener un orden establecido
                        agregar = np.array([materia.get(), nota.get(), profe.get()])
                        lista_datos = np.insert(lista_datos, agregar, axis=0)
                        del agregar

                    tk.Label(ventana, text='Ingrese datos opcionales correctamente:'
                        ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
                    tk.Label(ventana, text='Materia:').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
                    tk.Label(ventana, text='Nota:').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')
                    tk.Label(ventana, text='Profesor:').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='e')

                    tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=materia.get()).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
                    tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=nota.get()).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w')
                    tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=profe.get()).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w')

                    tk.Button(ventana, text='Anotar', command=anotar).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='nsew')

                else:
                    ventana = tk.Toplevel()
                    ventana.resizable(0,0)

                    def anotar():
                        agregar = np.array([materia.get(), nota.get(), profe.get()])
                        lista_datos = np.insert(lista_datos, agregar, axis=0)
                        del agregar     

                    tk.Label(ventana, text='Ingrese datos opcionales correctamente:'
                        ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
                    tk.Label(ventana, text='Materia:').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
                    tk.Label(ventana, text='Profesor:').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')
                    tk.Label(ventana, text='Nota:').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='e')

                    tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=materia.get()).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
                    tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=profe.get()).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w')
                    tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=nota.get()).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w')

                    tk.Button(ventana, text='Anotar', command=anotar).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='nsew')

            # Este bloque solo deberá ejecutarse si la lista tiene valores
            lista_datos = np.array([])
            if lista_datos.size != 0:
                opcionales_fm = tk.Frame(cont_fm)
                opcionales_fm.grid(row=2, column=0)

                tk.Label(opcionales_fm, text='Materia').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
                tk.Label(opcionales_fm, text='Nota').grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
                tk.Label(opcionales_fm, text='Profesor').grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsew')

                i = -1
                for i in lista_datos:
                    i += 1
                    j = -1
                    for j in lista_datos[i]:
                        j += 1
                        tk.Label(opcionales_fm, text=lista_datos[i][j]).grid(row=i+1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
                        tk.Label(opcionales_fm, text=lista_datos[i][j+1]).grid(row=i+1, column=1, sticky='nsew')
                        tk.Label(opcionales_fm, text=lista_datos[i][j+2]).grid(row=i+1, column=2, sticky='nsew')
            else:
                pass

            # Luego de pulsar la tecla "siguiente" se mostrará un saludo
            frase = str(f'¡Hola, {nombre.get()} {apellido.get()}!')
            text = tk.Text(resultado_fm, width=20, height=5)
            text.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
            text.insert(1.0, frase)
            text.config(state='disabled')

            tk.Label(resultado_fm, text='Agregar opcionales').grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

            tk.Radiobutton(resultado_fm, value=1, variable=op).grid(row=3, column=0)
            tk.Radiobutton(resultado_fm, value=2, variable=op).grid(row=4, column=0)

            tk.Label(resultado_fm, text='Nota/Profesor').grid(row=3, column=1)
            tk.Label(resultado_fm, text='Profesor/Nota').grid(row=4, column=1)

            # Este botón sirve para añadir más datos (opcionales)
            tk.Button(resultado_fm, text='Añadir', command=opcionales).grid(row=5, column=0)

        # Widgets para los datos de entrada:
        nombre = tk.StringVar()
        apellido = tk.StringVar()

        tk.Label(datos_fm, text='Ingrese datos:').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=None, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Label(datos_fm, text='Nombre:').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
        tk.Label(datos_fm, text='Apellido:').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')

        tk.Entry(datos_fm, textvariable=nombre).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
        tk.Entry(datos_fm, textvariable=apellido).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w')

        tk.Button(datos_fm, text='¡Siguiente!', command=siguiente).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

    def mainloop(self):

        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = App()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

Cuando intento ejecutar el código me aparece el error:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lista_datos' referenced before assignment`

**Información adicional:**

La siguiente imagen ejemplifica el cómo debería quedar la GUI después que el usuario ingreso su nombre, apellido y cargue dos datos adicionales.

[image: En este ejemplo solo se introducirán dos datos adicionales, pudiendo ser más cantidad.]

**Duda adicional:** Cuando se crean ventanas emergentes del tipo `tk.Toplevel`, ¿Al cerrarse quedan almacenadas en memoria las variables creadas dentro de ellas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es simplemente un problema de ámbito de variables. Toda variable que se cree en una función/método o se intente reasignar es tratada por defecto como una variable de ámbito local a su función/método, por lo que solo es accesible desde dicha función/método pero nunca desde fuera.

El problema es que dentro de la clausura `anotar` tratas de reasignara a la variable `lista_datos` definida en `opcionales`. Podrías arreglarlo con el uso de `nonlocal`:

```
def anotar():
    nonlocal lista_datos
```

No obstante hay más problemas en tu implementación:

- Capa vez que se llama a `opciones` se agrega todos los datos de nuevo, con ello duplicarías los labels con los datos del array, incluidos los tres que actúan de cabecera de la tabla.
- Si usas `numpy.insert`, el segundo argumento es el índice dónde insertar.
- Crees estar insertando filas y creando un array 2D (matriz), pero no, no es así como funciona `numpy.insert` o `numpy.append`:

  ```
  >>> lista_datos = np.array([])  
  >>> lista_datos = np.insert(lista_datos, 0, np.array([1, 2, 3]))
  >>> lista_datos = np.insert(lista_datos, 0, np.array([4, 5, 6]))
  >>> lista_datos
  array([4., 5., 6., 1., 2., 3.])
  >>> lista_datos.shape
  (6,)
  ```
- Derivado de lo anterior, dado que tienes un arrray 1D la forma en la que intentas iterar sobre el array es incorrecta.
- Los arrays de Numpy son unas estructuras perfectas y muy eficientes para almacenar datos numéricos y operar con ellos, pero no están pensadas para ser contenedores a los que estemos añadiendo o eliminando datos constantemente. Cada vez que haces algo así el array completo ha de copiarse en memoria. En éstos casos, una lista de Python (que simplemente almacena referencias a objetos arbitrarios) es una estructura infinitamente más eficiente.

En mi opinión te complicas demasiado generando clausuras en el inicializador, lo que por otra parte dificulta la legibilidad y mantenimiento futuro del código. Cuando como en éste caso el código se complique, aplica el casi siempre infalible "divide y vencerás", divide cada formulario, ventana, etc en clases, que cada clase se encargue de lo suyo y luego en cada inicializador dedicate solo a instanciar y construir por composición dejándolo lo más "limpio" posible.

Además, ésto te permitirá reutilizar las clases cuantas veces quieras o extenderlas por herencia si lo necesitas en un futuro.

Por ejemplo, reestructurando la app bastante, podrías hacer algo como:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Datos(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        # Widgets para los datos de entrada:
        self.nombre = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.apellido = tk.StringVar(self)

        tk.Label(
            self, text='Ingrese datos:'
            ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=None, sticky='nsew')
        tk.Label(self, text='Nombre:').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
        tk.Label(self, text='Apellido:').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='e')

        self._nombre_entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.nombre)
        self._nombre_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
        self._apellido_entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.apellido)
        self._apellido_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w')

        self._accept_btn = tk.Button(
            self, text='¡Siguiente!', command=self.on_accept
            )
        self._accept_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

    def on_accept(self):
        self.event_generate("<<NewDataAccept>>")
        self._accept_btn.config(state="disabled")
        self._nombre_entry.config(state="readonly")
        self._apellido_entry.config(state="readonly")


class DatosOpcionales(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        # Variable para las opciones
        self._op = tk.IntVar(self, value=1)

        # Lista con la tabla de datos
        self._datos = []

        # Cabeceras de la tabla
        self._headers = ['Materia', 'Nota', 'Profesor']
        self._headers_labels = [
            tk.Label(self, text=header) for header in self._headers
            ]

        # Widgets para elegir opción de formato de ingreso
        tk.Label(
            self, text='Agregar opcionales'
            ).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
        tk.Radiobutton(self, value=1, variable=self._op).grid(row=3, column=0)
        tk.Radiobutton(self, value=2, variable=self._op).grid(row=4, column=0)

        tk.Label(self, text='Nota/Profesor').grid(row=3, column=1)
        tk.Label(self, text='Profesor/Nota').grid(row=4, column=1)

        # Este botón sirve para añadir más datos (opcionales)
        tk.Button(
            self, text='Añadir', command=self.agregar_opcionales
            ).grid(row=5, column=0)

    def agregar_opcionales(self):
        if self._op.get() == 1:
            campos = ["Materia", "Nota", "Profesor"]
        else:
            campos = ["Materia", "Profesor", "Nota"]
        ventana = VentanaNuevosDatosOps(self, campos=campos)
        ventana.bind("<<NewOptionalDataAccept>>",  self._agregar_datos)

    def _agregar_datos(self, event):
        if not self._datos:
            for i, header in enumerate(self._headers_labels):
                header.grid(row=6, column=i, sticky='nsew')

        data = event.widget.data
        nuevos_datos = [data.get(header) for header in self._headers]
        self._datos.append(nuevos_datos)
        row = len(self._datos) + 6
        for i, dato in enumerate(nuevos_datos):
            tk.Label(self, text=dato).grid(row=row, column=i, sticky='nsew')


class VentanaNuevosDatosOps(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent, campos, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.resizable(False, False)

        # Asumo Python >= 3.7
        self.data = dict.fromkeys(campos)
        self._entries = []

        tk.Label(self, text='Ingrese datos opcionales correctamente:'
                        ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        for i,  campo in enumerate(campos):
            i += 1
            tk.Label(self, text=f"{campo}:").grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='e')
            entry = tk.Entry(self)
            entry.grid(row=i, column=1, sticky='w')
            self._entries.append(entry)

        tk.Button(
            self, text='Anotar', command=self.on_accept
            ).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    def on_accept(self):
        for campo, entry in zip(self.data, self._entries):
            self.data[campo] = entry.get()
        self.event_generate("<<NewOptionalDataAccept>>")
        self.destroy()



class Principal(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        # Formulario datos iniciales
        datos = Datos(self)
        datos.grid(row=0, column=0)
        datos.bind("<<NewDataAccept>>",  self.siguiente)

        # Text para mostrar datos
        self._text = tk.Text(self, width=20, height=5)

    def siguiente(self, event):
        self._text.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

        # Luego de pulsar la tecla "siguiente" se mostrará un saludo
        nombre = event.widget.nombre.get()
        apellido = event.widget.apellido.get()
        frase = f'¡Hola, {nombre} {apellido}!'
        self._text.insert(1.0, frase)
        self._text.config(state='disabled')

        resultado_fm = DatosOpcionales(self)
        resultado_fm.grid(row=2, column=0)


class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        # Contenedor principal
        self._cont_fm = Principal(self.root)
        self._cont_fm.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = App()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

---

Algunas observaciones:

- He optado por usar eventos personalizados para comunicar cada widgets con el padre e informar a éste que el formulario ha sido aceptado. Hay más posibilidades, pero ésta es bastante general y te permite cosas como tener varias ventanas secundarias abiertas enviando datos a la principal.
- En el caso del primer formulario con el nombre y apellido, he optado por deshabilitar los widgets una vez que se presiona siguiente. Si quieres otro comportamiento debes definirlo en su callback, en caso contrario crearás nuevos widgets solapando a los anteriores si el usuario vuelve a presionar el botón.
- Faltaría validar los formularios, se permite enviar formularios vacíos o con campos faltantes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Cuando se crean ventanas emergentes del tipo tk.Toplevel, ¿Al cerrarse quedan almacenadas en memoria las variables creadas dentro de ellas?

El comportamiento es igual que con cualquier otro objeto en Python, un widget no será destruido de memoria hasta que el GC lo haga y el GC solo lo destruirá cuando no existan referencias a dicho objeto o éstas sean circulares.

Es decir, mientras mantengas una referencia viva a un widgets seguirá existiendo en memoria aún cuando no sea mostrado.